# Erro sequelize com mysql no docker

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, sequelize-js

não consigo conectar a api ao mysql no docker, porem consigo rodar o mysql no docker pelo terminal

index.js

```
const db = require('../config/database');

const sequelize = new Sequelize(db)

module.exports = sequelize;
```

database.js

```
    database: 'mydb',
    username: 'mysql',
    password: 'pass',
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql'

}
```

```
sudo yarn sequelize db:create
```

retorna ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

o server.js que roda o express esta configurado para a porta 3001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo descrito, a base de dados está no Docker e a API está correndo na máquina local. Entretanto, a API está configurada para conectar-se a base de dados no endereço em localhost (IP 127.0.0.1 e porta 3306).

Sendo assim, o que faltou configurar foi a porta do seu container. Para iniciar um container e mapear uma porta local é preciso adicionar o parâmetro `p` ao comando `run`.

ex: `docker run --name exemplo-mysql -d -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw mysql`

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi corretamente, você vai subir no docker 2 containers, um com o banco e outro com sua API utilizando o NodeJS + Express.

Você pode fazer o vínculo de ambos utilizando o docker-compose. Aqui tem um exemplo de arquivo docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.4"
volumes:
  data_sistema:
services:
  db_sistema:
    image: mysql:5.6
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      - 3306
    volumes:
      - data_sistema:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=sistema
  app_sistema:
    build: ./
    image: app_sistema
    links:
      - db_sistema
    depends_on:
      - db_sistema
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db_sistema
      - DB_USERNAME=root
      - DB_PASSWORD=123456
      - DB_DATABASE=sistema
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - WAIT_HOSTS=db_sistema:3306
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

Perceba que neste exemplo eu tenho dois services, db_sistema que é o container do banco e app_sistema que é o container da API. Em ambas, eu tenho variáveis de sistema (seção environment). Perceba que em app_sistema, eu informo que o db_host é igual ao nome de serviço do banco dentro deste arquivo docker-compose.

No seu arquivo de conexão ao banco (database.js) você pode fazer a seguinte alteração para que o arquivo pegue os dados das variáveis de ambiente:

```
module.exports = {
  dialect: "mysql",
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
  operatorAliases: false,
  define: {
    timestamps: true,
    underscored: true,
    underscoredAll: true
  }
};
```

O ideal é deixar estas informações de conexão no arquivo .env da raiz do seu projeto, e puxar estes dados de lá, ao invés de deixar fixo no arquivo de conexão.